# Google Cloud Vision Min-Confidence for Label/Object Detection

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am using Google's Cloud Vision API for label detection and am trying to get the API to report more labels with lower confidence.  It seems like the current minimum confidence is about .5.

Amazon has the property `client.detect_labels(..., MinConfidence=50, ...)`

Does cloud vision have an equivalent parameter?

I tried the MinConfidence label and looking through all the docs but can't find anything on it.